# How to append text in edittext with real time speech to text?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have an `Edittext` for which I am using `speech to text` without `Activity`. I would like to append text in the `Edittext` instead of overwriting.

I tried

```
editText.append(result)

editText.getText()
editText.setText(gotText + result)
```

but. when i use, result be overlapping.

For example , if i speak `abc dragon`, result is `abc dragon abc dragon`

Hope your help !

This is my `Intent` and `RecognitionListner` code:

```
public void recognizeDirectly(Intent recognizerIntent)  {
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "ko-KR");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);

    SpeechRecognizer recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    recognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);
    recognizer.startListening(recognizerIntent);
}



private RecognitionListener listener = new RecognitionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Ready for speech " + params);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        progressBar1.setMax(10);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        progressBar1.setProgress((int) rmsdB);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        Log.d(TAG, getErrorText(error));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.d(TAG, "full results");
    }
    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            receiveResults(partialResults);
    }
    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

    }
};

private void receiveResults(Bundle results)  {

    if ((results != null) && results.containsKey(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION))  {
        List<String> heard = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        resultText = heard.get(0);
        txtText.append(resultText);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I seems like you're first `append()`'ing the `result`, and then reading it from the EditText object and setting the text again after you append the `result` to the already appended text.

Use only either

```
editText.append(result)
```

or

```
String gotText = editText.getText()
editText.setText(gotText + result)
```

Comment: i think, onPartialResults be called many times. and it overwriting again and again.. but when i use editText.append it make this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [TextView.append()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.

The Argument will be appended at the end of the Editable.

From Official Link :

> Convenience method: Append the specified text to the TextView's
>   display buffer, upgrading it to BufferType.EDITABLE if it was not
>   already editable.

For Example :

```
String title = bundle.getString("number1");
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.append(title);
```

If you want to set the only new value use this

```
editText.setText(title);
```

Comment: i think, onPartialResults be called many times. and it overwriting again and again.. but when i use editText.append it make this problem

Comment: it overwrite but give you result like as your problem if i speak abc dragon, result will not give abc dragon abc dragon instead it will give abc dragon. what else you want @TaeWooPark

Comment: Hi. i tried your solution. but still it is same...
 
           ArrayList<String> result = partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            editText.append(result.get(0));

i have to do something about onBufferReceived?

Answer (score 0):

You store current text in `onBeginningOfSpeech`:

```
public String currentText;

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    currentText = txtText.getText();
}
```

and then update append recognition result in `onPartialResults` and in `onResults`

```
@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    txtText.setText(currentText + " " +
                    results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION).get(0));
}
@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
    txtText.setText(currentText + " " +
                    results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION).get(0));
}
```